# Ferdinand Gotthold Max Eisenstein composer?

Tags: ho.history-overview

Eisenstein is said to have composed throughout his life.  Do any of his compositions survive?

Comment: This seems to be quite off-topic.

Comment: I agree, and have voted likewise. But this would make a great blog post...

Comment: The history of mathematics has both an inward aspect and an outward one.  Internal issues concern the flow of mathematical ideas, e.g. chains of influence, false starts, etc.  But mathematics is also a cultural enterprise and its past figures within the broader context of intellectual history.  When a mathematician of Eisenstein's statue (Gauss himself ranked Eisenstein alongside Archimedes and Newton) devotes significant time and energy to a non-mathematical pursuit, it is interesting to know whether or not his native mathematical genius finds distinctive expression in the other milieu.  

Comment: In any case this seems the likely forum to find someone who knows the disposition of Eisenstein's scientific and personal papers and who can direct me to support, if it exists, for this often repeated biographical claim.  Eisenstein's fame rests on his mathematics ... even if a MusicologyOverflow existed, it seems very unlikely that I would find anyone there who would even know the name.  

Comment: David F: "Interesting" and "on topic for MO" are not synonymous, even if one puts "Interesting peculiar to mathematicians".  My opinion (for what it's worth) is that what keeps MO a place where lots of mathematicians gather is the relative low frequency of questions of this form.  If the claim is often repeated in his biographies, surely the best route to find this information is to contact one of the biographers directly.  (If you wish to discuss this further, start a thread on meta.MO as it is unlikely that I will check this thread again.)
